# Using Celery tasks in Django to update aggregated data

Tags: python, django, celery

In my Django project, I have a use case where I have some complex Python functions which are **computationally expensive**: they involve numerous calculations based on a recurrence relation. They are already well optimized but still take a few seconds to run in some cases.

In this context, I'm thinking about **using Celery tasks** to carry out the calculations and to update aggregated data in dedicated tables of my PostgreSQL database. However, I have a feeling it's not going to be easy to **ensure the integrity of the data** and to **avoid unnecessary calculations**. Race conditions and unreliable error handling / retry mechanisms are some of the pitfalls I have in mind.

What are the best practices in this case? What do I need to pay particular attention to?

Are you aware of open source Django projects doing something similar?

I'm using Django 4.2, PostgreSQL 15, Redis 7.2 (as a cache), Celery 5.3, RabbitMQ 3.12 (as a broker).

Comment: I can't really understand what your problem is.  Maybe a simple transaction can solve your case? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Indeed, `transaction.atomic` is a good example of the kind of good habits I'm looking for. I'm simply looking for best practices like that one. I have to admit my question is more theoretical than what's used to be found on SO, but I would like to see some elegant pieces of code & concrete examples tackling that kind of issue, to be sure not to forget anything.